# Python# How to list all classes in a project which inherit another class?

Tags: python, django

How to list all classes in a project which inherit another class?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__subclasses__` method:

```
class_x.__subclasses__()
```

Comment: Tks u! But if its a multi inherit? 
__subclasses__ can use?

Comment: and python 3.6,3.7 can use? i dont see __subclasses__ in suggestions

Comment: Use for loops to get subclasses of subclasses. And yes, they work from anything inheriting from `object`, with python 3 classes do by default